# CSS media query with max height and max width not working

Tags: html, css

I am using media queries, in the below order:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1600px) and (max-height: 1024px) {
    .img {
        width: 150px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1600px) and (max-height: 900px) {
    .img {
        width: 100px;
    }
}
```

When my screen resolution is 1600x1024, the 1600x900 rule kicks in. When my screen resolution is 1600x1024, the 1600x900 rule also kicks in. This is according to the Developer Tools -> Elements -> Styles tab in chrome. The other rule is always crossed out for some reason. If I switch the order of the rules, then the 1600x1024 rule always kicks in. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Please check and edit your question text: You wrote two times "When my screen resolution is 1600x1024, ..." ...

Comment: You write about screen resolution, but: Is your viewport (= browser window) always full screen?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are applying both rules at the same time eg. your max-width is identical in both rules. Also remember that max-width targets the specified number and below and that min-width targets the specified number and above.

Can you try the following example?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1600px) and (max-height: 1024px) {
.img {
    width: 150px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 900px) { 
.img { 
    width: 100px; 
} 
}
```

In this case we don't have the same pixels specified as max-width.

More to be found about Media Queries here: https://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Comment: I need both rules